# redirect uri for spotify android api

Tags: uri, spotify

I am trying to implement spotify in my Android app through Spotify Android Api, when I am trying to get the access token, I am getting "#" instead of "?" to set the GET parameters in the redirect uri like this http://192.168.x.xx:8080/callbackspotify.php#access_token=BQA4Ze8sb-pBUvjJiNzNGbB08RzhNNgwJJ94k9Dp_QADbo_AagMaD7_J50PWY...&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600.
Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong or how to handle that # simbol?

Answer (score 0):

**Please put Redirect URIs in your Spotify developer dashboard like i share image**

[image: Redirect URIs in your Spotify developer dashboard]

Answer (score -2):

use ngrok, instead of your local IP